# Python call of import image as plane

Tags: python, scripting, add-on, command-line

I am building a simple python script that creates a plane with an image (image as plane addon). I call blender by the command line :

```
blender -P pattern_blender_smartphone.py
```

Here is the content of pattern_blender_smartphone.py :

```
import os
import bpy

def initScene():
    file = os.path.abspath('C:/Users/John/PycharmProjects/untitled/cowboy_bebop.jpg')
    bpy.ops.import_image.to_plane(
        use_shadeless=True,
        files=[{'name': os.path.basename(file)}],
        directory=os.path.dirname(file)
    )

initScene()
```

When i execute blender by the command line with this script i get these errors :

```
========================
   SCRIPT STARTING
========================
Error: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Program Files\Blender Foundation\Blender\2.75\scripts\addons\io_import_images_as_planes.py", line 320, in execute
    self.import_images(context)
  File "C:\Program Files\Blender Foundation\Blender\2.75\scripts\addons\io_import_images_as_planes.py", line 333, in import_images
    self.set_image_options(img)
  File "C:\Program Files\Blender Foundation\Blender\2.75\scripts\addons\io_import_images_as_planes.py", line 449, in set_image_options
    image.use_alpha = self.use_transparency
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'use_alpha'

location: C:\Program Files\Blender Foundation\Blender\2.75\scripts\modules\bpy\ops.py:189


Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
  File "<string>", line 43, in <module>
  File "<string>", line 11, in initScene
  File "C:\Program Files\Blender Foundation\Blender\2.75\scripts\modules\bpy\ops.py", line 189, in __call__
    ret = op_call(self.idname_py(), None, kw)
RuntimeError: Error: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Program Files\Blender Foundation\Blender\2.75\scripts\addons\io_import_images_as_planes.py", line 320, in execute
    self.import_images(context)
  File "C:\Program Files\Blender Foundation\Blender\2.75\scripts\addons\io_import_images_as_planes.py", line 333, in import_images
    self.set_image_options(img)
  File "C:\Program Files\Blender Foundation\Blender\2.75\scripts\addons\io_import_images_as_planes.py", line 449, in set_image_options
    image.use_alpha = self.use_transparency
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'use_alpha'

location: C:\Program Files\Blender Foundation\Blender\2.75\scripts\modules\bpy\ops.py:189


Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Program Files\Blender Foundation\Blender\2.75\scripts\addons\io_import_images_as_planes.py", line 320, in execute
    self.import_images(context)
  File "C:\Program Files\Blender Foundation\Blender\2.75\scripts\addons\io_import_images_as_planes.py", line 333, in import_images
    self.set_image_options(img)
  File "C:\Program Files\Blender Foundation\Blender\2.75\scripts\addons\io_import_images_as_planes.py", line 449, in set_image_options
    image.use_alpha = self.use_transparency
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'use_alpha'

location: C:\Program Files\Blender Foundation\Blender\2.75\scripts\modules\bpy\ops.py:189

location: C:\Program Files\Blender Foundation\Blender\2.75\scripts\modules\bpy\ops.py:189
Read new prefs: C:\Users\John\AppData\Roaming\Blender Foundation\Blender\2.75\config\userpref.blend
found bundled python: C:\Program Files\Blender Foundation\Blender\2.75\python
Saved session recovery to 'C:\Users\John\AppData\Local\Temp\quit.blend'

Blender quit
AL lib: (EE) UpdateDeviceParams: Failed to set 44100hz, got 48000hz instead
```

I have already tried to execute a blender instance and run the script with the GUI and it works but when i launch it by the command line i get errors.
Have you guys any ideas why it doesn't work?

Comment: This script already exists.
Import Image As Planes.

Comment: Yes thanks, i know this. Maybe i was not so clear. I am already using the addon but i am aiming at using the python call of the addon which is here bpy.ops.import_image.to_plane.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The python docs for [`os.abspath()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.path.html#os.path.abspath) says

> **os.path.abspath(path)** 
>    Return a normalized absolutized version of the pathname path. On most platforms, this is equivalent to calling the function normpath() as follows: normpath(join(os.getcwd(), path)).

that is it is adding the current directory (from `os.getcwd()`) onto the start of the absolute filepath that you have entered. This causes the load image to fail which then gives an error when attempting to set the `use_alpha` property.

The simple solution is to remove the `os.abspath()` call.